# Cannot link to stylesheet and javascript

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I am using the .htaccess file so you don't have to type index.php?url=

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 default
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but the problem I have now is I can't link any stylesheets and javascript files because it just goes straight to the index page.

Please help me find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add check for folder/file existence:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That worked great but I can't use the icons in bootstrap. - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons

Comment: You should be more specific about why exactly can't you use the icons. Probably icons file is just absent in a dir that stylesheet is referring to.

Comment: You were right it was because the stylesheet had the wrong URL. Thank you for your help. I will accept the answer :)